# How do I keep ferrets out of my aviary?

Tags: safety, birds

Is there a wire or something else that can be used to stop ferrets getting into aviaries? One ate my mum's owl over the weekend, and I want to keep them out so no one else gets eaten. (It could have also been a large rat.)

How can I keep the birds in my aviary safe?

Comment: can you provide us with photos of the aviary?

Comment: I used to have predator issues with weasels and my chicken coop, please post a photo of the aviary and then I will be able to give you a good recommendation on what kind of mesh to use and how to install it.

Comment: its  at my mums   so no pics sorry , we think its cus the wire used was too thin we have thickened the wire to a bigger gauge now and have put a  few traps around we were thinking on putting some plate steal arround the bottom too do they dig ??  would a motion activated light help ?